# Petición AJAX envía "Content-Type" incorrecto y recibe "HTTP 415 - Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc

estoy intentando realizar una petición AJAX usando Spring MVC pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Estado HTTP 415 – Unsupported Media Type

El servidor rechazó este requerimiento porque la entidad requerida se encuentra en un formato no soportado por el recurso requerido para el método requerido.
```

Entiendo que es porque posiblemente no se está enviando los datos en el formato JSON que el controlador de Spring espera, he intentado de varias maneras pero el problema persiste, este es el código del jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#position-form").submit(function(event) {
        savePosition();
    });
});

function savePosition() {
    var position = {}
    position["positionName"] = $("#position-name").val();
    position["positionDescription"] = $("#position-description").val();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : 'json',
        url : $('#position-form').attr('action'),
        data : JSON.stringify(position),
        timeout : 100000,
        headers : {
          'Accept' : 'application/json',
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        success : function(data) {
          console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
        },
        error : function(e) {
          console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        },
        done : function(e) {
        }
    });
}
```

y este es el formulario que pretende hacer la petición, el formulario está dentro de un modal:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<f:form action='save' id="position-form" method="post" modelAttribute="position">   
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Cargo</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <f:hidden path="id" />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="position-name">Nombre Del Cargo</label>
                    <f:input path="positionName" type="text" class="form-control" id="position-name" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="texto">Descripción</label>
                    <f:input path="positionDescription" type="text" class="form-control" id="position-description" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Atrás</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</f:form>
```

y por último este es el controlador:

```
@ResponseBody 
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String save(@RequestBody Position position) {

    System.out.println("Peticion AJAX");
    return "petición ajax hecha";
}
```

esta petición ni siquiera llega a `System.out.println("Peticion AJAX")`, tengo escrito `<mvc:annotation-driven />` en la configuración de spring.

Por último, estas son las cabeceras de la petición que el navegador muestra

**Accept**:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

**Accept-Encoding** gzip, deflate

**Accept-Language**:es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3

**Connection**:keep-alive

**Content-Lengt**:h38

**Content-Type**:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Cookie**:JSESSIONID=2EDD75CCC4631FDDD7ADBC7FD7A818B3Hostlocalhost:8080

La única manera en que ha "funcionado" es si edito el "Content-Type" con application/json y edito el cuerpo de los datos de la petición, pero esto se supone que con el código javascript donde está el ajax lo debería hacer.

De antemano les agradezco :)

Answer (score 1):

Luego de dar muchos rodeos, encontré la solución:

```
$("#position-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    savePosition();
});
```

Había que agregar la línea `event.preventDefault()` y con esto la petición ajax funciona sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

En el form de tu página HTML, tienes un typo: `id="positon-form"` debería ser `id="position-form"`, ya que este es el id al que tu código javascript hace referencia:

```
$("#position-form").submit(function(event) {
    savePosition();
});
```

Por eso al dar click en el botón guardar, el formulario se envía con un `Content-Type` incorrecto, ya que no se está ejecutando la función `savePosition()` que es la encargada de configurar el `Content-Type` a `application/json`.

Comment: no me habia percatado de eso, gracias!

Comment: he hecho los arreglos respectivos pero el problema persiste, las cabeceras siguen igual